# cannot find user-defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @lastname VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @birthdate VARCHAR(25)
SELECT @lastname = 'Smith'

SELECT @birthdate = '19-Apr-36'

INSERT INTO [TEST_TABLE](lastname, birthdate) 
VALUES (@lastname, (dbo.scrubDateDOBString(@birthdate)))
```

Anyway to make preceding query work in ssms08?

I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Cannot find either column "dbo" or
>   the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.scrubDateDOBString", or
>   the name is ambiguous.

The following works:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (lastname, birthdate) 
VALUES ('test', (dbo.scrubDateString('2/2/48')))
```

Comment: Does that function exist? Do you have permission to execute the function?

Comment: What does scrubDateDOBString look like i.e. what does it return? It seems like it returns a table.

Comment: returns a datetime and i did a test a similar test that worked. See update of OP.

Comment: If `@birthdate` is a **date** - why aren't you using the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes?? Using `varchar(x)` for dates is always prone to conversion errors and issues with language and date format settings .....

Comment: Your second example uses a different function (no `DOB`), so it's working it irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using a `INSERT INTO...SELECT`

```
DECLARE @lastname VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @birthdate VARCHAR(25)
SET @lastname = 'Smith'       
SET @birthdate = '19-Apr-36'  

insert into [TEST_TABLE] (lastname,birthdate) 
SELECT @lastname, dbo.scrubDateDOBString(@birthdate)
```

You might have to cast your @`birthdate` to a different format

if you need to case it, you can do it this way:

```
insert into [TEST_TABLE] (lastname,birthdate) 
SELECT @lastname, dbo.scrubDateDOBString(cast(@birthdate as datetime))
```

Comment: if you just do a SELECT dbo.scrubDateDOBString('19-Apr-36') does it work with the date in that format?

Comment: i started a new query window with just the SELECT test and it worked. so i copied the rest of the code over and now it works. weird! no difference i can see right away between the 2 sessions.